# How to source/name a 20 pin 19 position usb 3.0 connector

Tags: usb, connector, source

I am trying to find the male end of the connectors found on many modern computer motherboards which are used to connect USB 3.0 from a case to the motherboard. These have 2 rows of 10 positions (so 20 positions) but with only 19 pins (corner one missing). The plastic walls around the set of 19 pins are keyed too.

Searching on the TE website and digikey and others pretty much always gives either 20 pin connectors with all pins present, or 19 pins but the pins offset from each other. I can find many such connectors on stores like Amazon, alibaba, ebay, etc, but we need a higher volume from a reputable distributer like digikey. We also have high enough volume that we can't just modify existing ones we find on eBay via simply snipping the pin.

Is there a terminology issue? A term I often find is "19 pin 20 pin" and "idc", but they aren't giving me anything close to a specific part with a part number from te connectivity or digikey or mouser or similar.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amphenol has, for example, the G823J201240BHR ([Mouser](https://www.mouser.de/ProductDetail/Amphenol-Commercial-Products/G823J201240BHR?qs=%2Fha2pyFadujHFWrZ654NkNtnvGm4TU57yvNtXf8NkD1u%252BwBO2o85mg%3D%3D), [Digikey](https://www.digikey.de/products/de?keywords=G823J201240BHR)). Mouser has 2,000 in stock as of today, or 11 week lead time.

"Box header for USB 3.0 internal connector, straight type"

(Image removed to respect Amphenol copyright terms. See datasheet.)

No affiliation with any of the above mentioned firms.

Answer (score 2):

That's a "USB Internal Connector Cable" connector, according to intel's standardization efforts:

https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/docs/io/universal-serial-bus/usb3-internal-connector-cable-specification.html

You're essentially looking for [this](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/amphenol-icc-commercial-products/G823J201240BHR/13682992?s=N4IgTCBcDaIK4GcBGACAlgYwyAugXyA) amphenol connector or siblings.

Answer (score 2):

As noted, "USB Internal Connector Cable" is the designation for that particular part.

In general, those headers with housings are made so that you can easily pull pins out.  If you order sufficient quantities from the manufacturer you can get them with the pins left out.  If you're small volume (I do *not* know at what point the manufacturer will pull pins for you) then you can do it yourself, or you can specify to your assembly house that they do it.

So you can always make a custom keyed header for your design -- you just have to pay someone to pull, or leave out, pins.